# Llenar un texto desde un select

Tags: javascript

Tengo un código que mediante javascript debe llenar un *input text* a partir de un *select* y no me esta funcionando.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script text=javascript>
var select = document.getElementById('dropdown');
select.addEventListener('change', function(event) {
  var select = event.target;
  var indiceSeleccionado = select.selectedIndex;
  var elementoSeleccionado = select.options[indiceSeleccionado];
  var texto = document.getElementById('mytext');

  texto.value = select.value;

})
</script>
</head>
<input type="text" id="mytext">

<select id="dropdown" >

  <option value="">None</option>
  <option value="text1">text1</option>
  <option value="text2">text2</option>
  <option value="text3">text3</option>
  <option value="text4">text4</option>
</select>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Y me corre perfecto aqui https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Mueve el `script` al final del `body` o ponle un `defer`. El motivo por el que no te funciona en tu servidor (pero sí en JSFiddle) es porque estás intentando leer elementos que aún no existen en el DOM cuando se ejecuta el script.

Answer (score 1):

Tienes que mover el javascript al final de la pagina para poder lograrlo:

```html
<input type="text" id="mytext">

<select id="dropdown" >

  <option value="">None</option>
  <option value="text1">text1</option>
  <option value="text2">text2</option>
  <option value="text3">text3</option>
  <option value="text4">text4</option>
</select>

<script text=javascript>
var select = document.getElementById('dropdown');
select.addEventListener('change', function(event) {
  var select = event.target;
  var indiceSeleccionado = select.selectedIndex;
  var elementoSeleccionado = select.options[indiceSeleccionado];
  var texto = document.getElementById('mytext');

  texto.value = select.value;

})
</script>
```

El código de la página se ejecuta a modo de cascada, de arriba hacia abajo según esta se carga. Cuando un código javascript se carga y ejecuta antes que el elemento al que hace referencia este no puede encontrarse, entonces, tu código `var select = document.getElementById('dropdown');` se ejecuta antes de que el *select* se haya renderizado y por eso no lo puede encontrar.